# Multiply each element of a numpy array by a tuple

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D numpy image array with shape `(height, width, 3)`, and BGR tuples as elements, I want to multiply each element by a kernel to extract the B/G/R channels individually. The blue kernel, for example, would be `(1, 0, 0)`. Something like this:

```
# extact color channel
def extract_color_channel(image, kernel):
   channel = np.copy(image)
   height, width = image.shape[:2]
   for y in range(0, height):
      for x in range(0, width):
         channel[y,x] = image[y, x] * kernel
   return channel

# extract blue channel
def extract_blue(image):
   return extract_color_channel(image, (1, 0, 0))
```

What is the most efficient "numpy way" to do this?

Comment: Why not just `image[:,:,0]`?

Comment: I'm new to numpy, could you explain/point me to an explanation of `0` there? Why not `image[:,:,kernel]`?

Comment: read the numpy doc... this is completely basic!

Comment: It is basic indexing, which means you want to extract a slice from an array, then just specify the corresponding index. See [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) here.

Comment: Ok I see what's happening here. In the context of an image, `image[:,:,0]` tosses the red and green channels out, and produces a grayscale image from the blue channel. Is there a way to do this without throwing those channels away, but just leaving them set to 0? So if I output the image it's still displayed in color? Instead of slicing out the blue channel with `image[:,:,0]`, instead I just zero the 1 and 2 channels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a sample array:

```
In [220]: arr = np.arange(5*5*3).reshape(5,5,3)
```

Basic indexing is the most efficient way (this will be a `view`)

```
In [221]: arr[:,:,0]
Out[221]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12],
       [15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
       [30, 33, 36, 39, 42],
       [45, 48, 51, 54, 57],
       [60, 63, 66, 69, 72]])
```

The `[1,0,0]` list is not what you want.  But you could cast it as a bool array.

```
In [222]: kernel = np.array([1,0,0],dtype=bool)
In [223]: kernel
Out[223]: array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [224]: arr[:,:,kernel].shape
Out[224]: (5, 5, 1)
In [225]: arr[:,:,kernel].squeeze()
Out[225]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12],
       [15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
       [30, 33, 36, 39, 42],
       [45, 48, 51, 54, 57],
       [60, 63, 66, 69, 72]])
```

Notice that the shape with the boolean is still 3d.  If you don't want that, then you'll need to reshape or squeeze that last dimension out.  This indexing is slower since it makes a `copy`.

This boolean indexing is the equivalent of

```
In [226]: arr[:,:,[0]].shape
Out[226]: (5, 5, 1)
```

where `[0]` is the location of the 'true' value(s) in `kernel`.

You could also use a `dot` (matrix product):

```
In [228]: np.dot(arr,[1,0,0])
Out[228]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12],
       [15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
       [30, 33, 36, 39, 42],
       [45, 48, 51, 54, 57],
       [60, 63, 66, 69, 72]])
```

It will be slower than indexing.

Element multiplication:

In [232]: arr*np.array([1,0,0])
Out[232]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 3,  0,  0],
        [ 6,  0,  0],
        [ 9,  0,  0],
        [12,  0,  0]],

```
   [[15,  0,  0],
    [18,  0,  0],
       ....
    [66,  0,  0],
    [69,  0,  0],
    [72,  0,  0]]])
```

In this multiplication the [1,0,0] behaves as though it were a (1,1,3) array, and broadcasts with the (n,n,3) just fine.

Comment: This is helpful but I'm missing something. If in my sample array I instead do: `arr = np.ones([5, 5, 3]) * 255`, that sets every "pixel" to white. What I want is to then run `extract_blues` to get a flat blue image, `extract_reds` to get a flat red image, etc. I don't want to change the shape of my array. In my ones example every value `arr[y,x]` produces `(255, 255, 255)`. After `extract_blues`, every value `arr[y,x]` should produce `(255, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Sorry I may have gotten off on the track with the comparison to `[:,:,0]`.  Sure you can multiply a (n,n,3) by (3,).  They broadcast together.  Other math works as well.  The `dot` is such a multiplication plus a sum.  I was focusing on the 'extracting', not the modification or construction of a new image.

Comment: Yeah, word choice :/. At any rate this put me on the right track. And "extracting" to grayscale is probably what I want to do in the long run anyways. Accepting this, thanks for the help.